# Error: Failed to update the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

After recently moving my repo, completing a new ebinit and exports to eb files, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Failed to update the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment
```

Using git aws.push, I'm not getting any more information regarding the error.

Has anyone experienced something similar and have any ideas of how to overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
eb status
```

Is the best way to debug failures from the EB CLI

Answer (score 0):

I got this error once when i had created a new eb branch and forgot to do:

> eb start.